# Select a specific record from a select query

Tags: sql, oracle

**EDIT** : My actual select looks like this :

```
select x.id, x.name, x.status, y.edit, y.date
, LEAD(y.date) OVER ( PARTITION BY x.id ORDER BY y.date ) - date AS edit_diff
from (table1 x left join table2 y on x.id = y.id)
where x.id = 1
```

the result is as follows :

```
ID    Name    Status    Edit    Date          edit_diff
1     n1      closed    edt1      01/01/2005  6
1     n1      closed    edt1      07/01/2005  8
1     n1      closed    edt2      15/01/2005  5
1     n1      closed    edt2      20/01/2005  3
1     n1      closed    edt3      23/01/2005  null
```

I actually want my select to return only the edits with the oldest dates :

```
ID    Name    Status    Edit    Date          edit_diff
1     n1      closed    edt1      01/01/2005  14
1     n1      closed    edt2      15/01/2005  8
1     n1      closed    edt3      23/01/2005  null
```

Can you help ? I tried a `(SELECT edit from mytable WHERE DATE = MAX(DATE))`but it's not working since I have `order by`on the same query. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to assign a sequential value to each edit and just choose the first one:

```
SELECT id, name, status, edit, date, edit_diff
FROM (SELECT id, name, status, edit, date,
             LEAD(date) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date ) - date AS edit_diff,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, edt ORDER BY date) as seqnum
      FROM mytable
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

On closer inspection, you are not selecting rows but aggregating them.  So, this seems to be more what you want:

```
SELECT id, name, status, edit, min(date), sum(edit_diff)
FROM (SELECT id, name, status, edit, date,
             LEAD(date) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date ) - date AS edit_diff
      FROM table1 x left join table2 y on x.id = y.id
     ) t
GROUP BY id, name, status, edit;
```

EDIT:

The version should just be:

```
SELECT id, name, status, edit, min(date), sum(edit_diff)
FROM (SELECT x.id, x.name, x.status, y.edit, y.date,
             LEAD(y.date) OVER (PARTITION BY x.id ORDER BY y.date ) - y.date AS edit_diff
      FROM mytable
      WHERE x.id = 1
     ) t
GROUP BY id, name, status, edit;
```

Comment: I tried your second code and it throws this error : ORA-00904: `"x"."name": invalid identifier`. FYI id, name, status and edit come from different tables (I don't know if this has an incident ) : `select x.id, x.name, x.status, y.edit, y.date
from (table1 x left join table2 y on x.id = y.id)
where x.id = 1 `

Comment: There is no `x.name` or `y.edit` in my answer nor in your question.  If you have a different question, you should ask it as another question.  This is intended to answer the question that you *asked*, using the `mytable` table name that *you* supplied.

Comment: My mistake, sorry for that :) I updated my question with the right query (I thaught it would have no incidence on the solution since I'm trying to manipulate the result of the select query, not the query itself...)

Comment: That solved my problem..and helped me understand the utility of `group by`thanks :)